# Is this sentence in present continuous or not?

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous

I have noticed that some engineers put on their profiles the following:

```
Working on "project-name" product.
```

Is this sentence in present continuous or not?

Shouldn't it be like this:

```
Work on "project-name" project.
```

Comment: Yes, the first phrase (not a sentence!) is in the _present continuous._ The _present continuous_ is used when the subject is currently involved in the project: the work is still _continuing._ If the subject had completed work on the project, he would use the _simple past:_ "Work**ed** on "project-name" product." The _simple present_ would not make sense here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As P. E. Dant points out, this is not a complete sentence anyway, so you can't really say it's wrong.  It's just a matter of how you interpret it.

Usually when you read something like this in an online profile or a resume, you should think of these things as having an implied **"I am"** at the beginning:  (I am) **working on the Foobartron project**.  It's present continuous because it's an ongoing event.

Leaving off "I am" is [a practice which is called *subject pronoun drop*, or *diary drop*](http://www.isle-linguistics.org/resources/weir2009.pdf) because it's often used when people are writing in their diary, and which is sometimes used in cases like profiles or resumes so you don't have to keep repeating "I am" over and over.